# App doesn't work after enabling Firebase AppCheck (403 error)

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, firebase-app-check

I followed the official guide to enable AppCheck. I registered my site for reCAPTCHA v3 and registered my app to use AppCheck in the firebase console. I have not yet enforced anything.

In one of my NgModules I did the following:

```
import {
  initializeAppCheck,
  ReCaptchaV3Provider,
  provideAppCheck,
} from "@angular/fire/app-check";

...

provideAppCheck(() => {
  return initializeAppCheck(getApp(), {
    provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(environment.firebase.recaptchaKey),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
  });
}),
```

After doing what I've mentioned above, my app no longer works. I get the following error once when my site loads:

```
Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unknown]: Fetching auth token failed: AppCheck: Fetch server returned an HTTP error status. HTTP status: 403. (appCheck/fetch-status-error).
```

And this one is printed from time to time:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: cancelled ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: cancelled undefined
```

In the firebase console under AppCheck API monitoring, all requests are marked as `Unverified: outdated client requests`

In the google recaptcha admin console, it says total requests 0.

The above happens on a deployed version of my app whose domain I have listed in the settings of the google recaptcha admin console.

What could be the issue? How do I debug it?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this @Jesper? I have a very similar situation.

Comment: It works now, but I'm not 100% sure what fixed it. I realised that the app I had deployed had the `production` flag set to `false`, so one of the things I tried was to set that to `true`.